# Extrapolation from curved datapoints

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, extrapolation

I can't quite wrap my head around on how to extrapolate from a dataset where the points are not ordered, i.e. be decreasing for 'x'. like so:

http://www.pic-host.org/images/2014/07/21/0b5ad6a11266f549.png

I got that I need to create a plot for the x and y values seperately. So the code that gets me this: (The points are ordered)

```
x = bananax
y = bananay

t = np.arange(x.shape[0], dtype=float) 
t /= t[-1]
nt = np.linspace(0, 1, 100) 

x1 = scipy.interpolate.spline(t, x, nt) 
y1 = scipy.interpolate.spline(t, y, nt)

plt.plot(nt, x1, label='data x')
plt.plot(nt, y1, label='data y')
```

Now I got the interpolated splines. I guess I have to do the extrapolation for f(nt)=x1 and f(nt)=y1 respectivly. I get how to interpolate from the data with a simple linear regression but I'm missing how to get a more complex spline(?) extrapolated from it.
The aim is to let the extrapolated function follow the curvature of the datapoints. (At one end at least)

Cheers, and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks this got me on the right track. What worked for me was:

```
x = bananax
y = bananay

#------ fit a spline to the coordinates, x and y axis are interpolated towards t
t = np.arange(x.shape[0], dtype=float) #t is # of values
t /= t[-1] #t is now devided from 0 to 1
nt = np.linspace(0, 1, 100) #nt is array with values from 0 to 1 with 100 intermediate values

x1 = scipy.interpolate.spline(t, x, nt) #The x values where spline should estimate the y values
y1 = scipy.interpolate.spline(t, y, nt)

#------ create a new linear space for nnt in which an extrapolation from the interpolated spline will be made 
nnt = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100) #values <0 are extrapolated (interpolation started at the tip(=0)

x1fit = np.polyfit(nt,x1,3) #fits a polynomial function of the nth order with the spline as input, output are the function parameters
y1fit = np.polyfit(nt,y1,3)

xpoly = np.poly1d(x1fit) #genereates the function based on the parameters obtained by polyfit
ypoly = np.poly1d(y1fit)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you're on the right track in that you're creating a parametric curve (creating x(t) and y(t)) because the points are ordered.  Part of issue seems to be that the `spline` function is giving you back discrete values rather than the form and parameters of the spline. `scipy.optimize` has some nice tools that will help you find functions rather than calculating points

If you've got any insight into the underlying process generating the data I suggest that you use that to help select a functional form for fitting. These more free-form methods will give you a degree of flexibility to do so.

Fit x(t) and y(t) and hold onto the resulting fitting functions. They'll be generated with data from `t=0` to `t=1` but nothing* will stop you from evaluating them outside that range.

I can recommend the following links for guidance on curve fitting procedure:

short: http://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2011/05/curve-fitting-using-fmin.html

long: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/keflavich/4042018

*almost nothing